# Cakephp2: How to display number of contents within the link in the cakephp2

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, tag-cloud

I'm new to cakephp2 and I came to be find some solution.
The problem is that I have a list of links in cakephp2 like this

[image]

But the problem is that I want to display the number of contents like the sample below

[image]

For a amature like me it is a bit too difficult.I do not know how to implement the number of lists or contents  in the link or how to call this .It would be great if the pros like you can help me out! 
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: SO isn't the place where people do all the work for you, it's about helping to solve specific problems. So if you need help, then you should specify the actual programming releated problem that you are facing. **http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask**

Comment: Sorry.As a junior high student I thought it was better to ask first to experienced programmers, because I'm tired of making crappy sites as a hobby. But I'm grateful for people  who help  me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need a HABTM setup like this:

```
Class Tag extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Tag';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Article' => array(
            'className' => 'Article',
            'joinTable' => 'articles_tags',
            'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'article_id',
            )
        );
}

Class ArticlesTag extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'ArticlesTag';
}

Class Article extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Article';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'className' => 'Tag',
            'joinTable' => 'articles_tags',
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            )
        );
}
```

Add following to your AppModel, you will never look back:

```
class AppModel extends Model {

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

In controller:

```
$results = $this->Tag->find('all, array(
    'contain' => array('Article)
    ));

$this->set('results', $results);
```

In view:

```
<ul class="tags">

<?php foreach ($results as $data) : ?>
<li class="tag"><?php 

echo $this->Html->link($data['Tag']['name'] . ' (' . count($data['Article']) . ')', 
    '/tag/' . $data['Tag']['slug'],
    array('title' => 'View articles for ' . $data['Tag']['name'], 'escape' => false));

?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Hope this helps.